# Lots of security cameras but no DVR, what one do i get?

Tags: security

I recently purchased a 4 acre property, and the seller left all of his security cameras but took the dvrs.

There's at least 10 cameras. Some are newer models but there some that look to be from 4-5 years ago. I don't know much about setting up a security system, can I purchase a universal dvr to connect all the cameras? Or would it be cheaper to just buy my own cameras that come with a dvr?

Most of the cams have red/yellow ends on them so hopefully that will tell you what type they are. ?

I really would like to use the cams already here because there already mounted and wired throughout the property.

Any advice/help is very much appreciated,

Thank you!

Comment: What is the model number of one of the cameras?  What kind of cable comes out of them?

Comment: DVRs for camera systems are called NVRs.  Use that for google.

Comment: From wikipedia: An NVR is typically deployed in an IP video surveillance system. Network video recorders are distinct from digital video recorders (DVR) as their input is from a network rather than a direct connection to a video capture card or tuner. Rob's question is likely regarding an analog camera configuration, which would exclude NVRs from a technical standpoint.

Comment: Post a picture of the wires where the DVRs sat. Does the wiring include power as well, or did the DVR power the cameras?

Answer (score 1):

The older security camera systems use "traditional" video feeds, typically using RCA type connectors. That's likely the red connection on your camera. The yellow connector may be audio.

You should also have a barrel type connection for power.

The termination at the DVR end should involve connecting the RCA to the DVR and the barrel end to a power source. I managed to contact the new owner of my old DVR and he has confirmed that the power supply is a 12 volt DC 2 ampere unit. In this case, two cameras were powered by one power supply, through a splitter provided with the equipment.

This is consistent with other camera gear I've had in the past, requiring 1 ampere current at 12 volts DC.

You can test your cameras, one at a time, if you have an old VCR. Apply power to the barrel lead, connect the RCA to the VCR input and select appropriate settings on the VCR, connected to a television or monitor.

If you don't have three independent wires in a cable running from each camera, the above does not apply. Newer systems use POE, power over ethernet and require an injector at the DVR end and also require that the camera have the ability to accept such an input. It does not appear that your connectors qualify for this concern.

Comment: Downvoter, please comment to explain.

Comment: I too am wondering why I got a down vote. I believe I answered a couple of the questions as well as provided additional information to assist in the decision to purchase a new full system or only a recording device.